# Creating Cardano Non-Fungible Tokens with royalties for newbies

Tags: smart-contract, nft

I've been looking around since last week and I need directions to create my own non-fungible tokens with royalties.

Do I need to learn how to create a smart contract for this myself? or are there templates that I can trust?

I'm looking for best practices and good sources.

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a discussion about this topic on the [Cardano forum](https://forum.cardano.org/t/cip-royalties/68599/2).

Some members of the community created a CIP that you can see on [GitHub](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/pull/116).

This is the most recent information there is (and it's still work in progress). Since native assets can be sent around without any smart contracts, royalties can't be enforced for Cardano NFTs. With the proposal in the CIP, you rely on the honesty of the people (or at least the NFT marketplaces) who sell your NFTs.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably need to write the smart contract for yourself.  There isn't really a set of well tested templates or anything like that (as far as I know) besides the sample exercise code provided in the plutus pioneers program.

Comment: Do you have the sample exercise code at hand? or link to it?